# Add XmlAttribute to many XmlElements of a serializeable object

Tags: xml, vb.net, generics, serialization

I need to add an XmlAttribute ("isCanon=true/false") to around 30 of 45 fields for each planet in my planets.xml.  I have manually added the attribute to all the fields for one planet and saved that as a test.xml to then paste xml as class but, it does not generate working code.  I get a "InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize member 'isCanon' of type System.Object. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types."  I am also trying to do this using generics so I dont have to make 30-45 new class for each field of Planet (I dont know if generics is the right way to do this or not).

```
<System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class Canon(Of T)

    Private a As Boolean
    Private i As T

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property isCanon()
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()>
    Public Property inner()

End Class
```

This is what visual studio generates when I paste as class for the test xml for just the x coordinate element:

```
Partial Public Class planetsPlanet

    Private xcoodField As planetsPlanetXcood

    Public Property xcood() As planetsPlanetXcood
        Get
            Return Me.xcoodField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.xcoodField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Partial Public Class planetsPlanetXcood

    Private isCanonField As Boolean

    Private valueField As Decimal

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property isCanon() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.isCanonField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.isCanonField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()>
    Public Property Value() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.valueField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And this is my simplified planets.xml with only one planet in it for testing (original planets.xml contains over 3,000 planets that are serialized into objects, modified, then written to a new planets.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- This file is for testing the planets -->
<planets>
    <planet>
        <xcood isCanon="true">-123.764</xcood>
        <ycood isCanon="true">272.182</ycood>
        <id isCanon="true">A Place</id>
        <name isCanon="true">A Place</name>
        <sysPos isCanon="false">3</sysPos>
        <spectralType isCanon="true">K1V</spectralType>
        <spectralClass isCanon="true">K</spectralClass>
        <subtype isCanon="true">1.0</subtype>
        <luminosity isCanon="true">V</luminosity>
        <orbitRadius isCanon="false">1.00000011</orbitRadius>
        <orbitEccentricity isCanon="false">0.0167086</orbitEccentricity>
        <orbitInclination isCanon="false">1.57869</orbitInclination>
        <satellite isCanon="false">Moon</satellite>
        <gravity isCanon="false">1.0</gravity>
        <dayLength isCanon="false">24.0</dayLength>
        <percentWater isCanon="false">75</percentWater>
        <volcanism isCanon="false">2</volcanism>
        <tectonics isCanon="false">2</tectonics>
        <landMass isCanon="false">Asia</landMass>
        <landMass isCanon="false">Africa</landMass>
        <landMass isCanon="false">Antarctica</landMass>
        <landMass isCanon="false">Australia</landMass>
        <landMass isCanon="false">Europe (Geneva)</landMass>
        <landMass isCanon="false">North America</landMass>
        <landMass isCanon="false">South America</landMass>
        <landMass isCanon="false">Mars - (Koryo)</landMass>
        <landMass isCanon="false">Luna - (Luna City)</landMass>
        <nadirCharge isCanon="false">false</nadirCharge>
        <zenithCharge isCanon="false">false</zenithCharge>
        <pressure isCanon="false">3</pressure>
        <pressureAtm isCanon="false">1.0</pressureAtm>
        <atmMass isCanon="false">1.0</atmMass>
        <albedo isCanon="false">0.33</albedo>
        <greenhouse isCanon="false">1.0</greenhouse>
        <temperature isCanon="false">30</temperature>
        <climate isCanon="false">TEMPERATE</climate>
        <lifeForm isCanon="false">MAMMAL</lifeForm>
        <habitability isCanon="false">7</habitability>
        <pop isCanon="false">10</pop>
        <government isCanon="false">Democracy (Representative)</government>
        <controlRating isCanon="false">5</controlRating>
        <socioIndustrial isCanon="true">C-C-A-C-D</socioIndustrial>
        <hpg isCanon="false">A</hpg>
        <faction isCanon="true">UND</faction>
        <desc>Despite A Place's poor soil making agriculture nearly impossible the planet was settled to take advantage of its abundance of natural resources. For most of its history A Place has relied on its neighbor, Bountiful Harvest for food. Unfortunately, when there are disruptions in shipping, such as during the 1st Succession War, food shortages begin almost immediately. During the 1st Succession War the lack of food resulted in nearly 90% of the planet's million inhabitants starving.</desc>
        <event>
            <date isCanon="true">2235-01-01</date>
            <faction isCanon="true">IND</faction>
        </event>
        <event>
            <date isCanon="true">2571-01-01</date>
            <faction isCanon="true">LA</faction>
        </event>
        <event>
            <date isCanon="true">3040-01-19</date>
            <faction isCanon="true">FC</faction>
        </event>
        <event>
            <date isCanon="true">3057-12-01</date>
            <faction isCanon="true">ARDC</faction>
        </event>
        <event>
            <date isCanon="true">3067-04-24</date>
            <faction isCanon="true">LA</faction>
        </event>
        <event>
            <date isCanon="true">3130-01-01</date>
            <faction isCanon="true">CJF,LA</faction>
        </event>
        <event>
            <date isCanon="true">3135-01-01</date>
            <faction isCanon="true">CJF</faction>
        </event>
    </planet>
</planets>
```

And a portion of the class that actually serializes, generates missing data if the planet does not have everything filled out, and then writes the new planets.xml

```
Private Sub serialPlanets()

    Dim serial As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Planets))
    Dim p As New Planets

    Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Planets\planetsTemplate.xml")
    While reader.Read()

        p = serial.Deserialize(reader)

    End While
    reader.Close()

    Dim Wsettings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings With {
    .Indent = True,
    .IndentChars = (ControlChars.Tab),
    .ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document,
    .WriteEndDocumentOnClose = True}

    For Each planet In p.planetArray()
    'tons of stuff to generate various planet attributes
    Next

    Array.Sort(p.planetArray)
    Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Planets\planets.xml", Wsettings)
    serial.Serialize(writer, p)
    writer.Flush()
    writer.Close()

End Sub
```

A complete example of my code can be found on my github [PlanetsXML](https://github.com/BLOODWOLF333/PlanetsXML) with the problem mainly involving Planets.vb and objPlanets.vb.